# Espresso always gives me success whether dialog having text success or fail

Tags: android, dialog, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for my UI testing, I am new to this framework, I have written some code by doing some research and tried to run the code. I am trying to get the existence of dialog after API get hit. In my case, the dialog text for success is "success" and for failure is "Failure". But my test is giving me the green flag for both the cases it's showing that the test has been passed, Even if my condition does not match with the expected result.

Here is the code:-

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {
    String emailAddress,password;
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void prepareData(){
         emailAddress = "dsf@gmail.com";
         password = "Password123#";
        onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).perform(typeText(emailAddress), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.et_password)).perform(typeText(password), closeSoftKeyboard());
    }

    @Test
    public void clickSignUpButtonAfterFillingForm_showProgressAndSuccessScreen() {

        onView(withId(R.id.btn_login)).perform(click());
//        onView(withId(R.id.tv_login_email_error)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
//        onView(withId(R.id.tv_login_password_error)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            onView(withText("Faliure"))
                    .inRoot(isDialog()) // <---
                    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The credentials I have passed is correct and as per my condition, the test should get fail as I am expecting a dialog with text "Failure" but as the credentials, I am filling is correct so the dialog will come up with "success" message.

Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong in the code ?

Regards

Comment: remove try catch and check

Comment: @hasan_shaikh, I removed but it does not help